# Windows Audio Player for Primary School musical

Tags: audio, music

Here in the Netherlands, it is tradition to end the primary school period with a musical. For this I need an audio player that makes life easy, but I can't find it.

What I need is very simple. When I press the spacebar, a song plays. When the song is over, the playback stops. When I press spacebar again, the next song starts. I don't want to take the risk of manually having to pause it when the song is over, because I don't want the next song to start when it's not supposed to. It doesn't seem like too tall of an order, but I haven't found a player that can do this yet. Any advice?

Comment: Hello, which ones didn't meet your expectations? It seems like a simple enough config - no autoplay and keyboard shortcut to play with spacebar. Unless i'm misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Most of popular 3rd party media players should be able to meet these quite easy requirements, after a bit of configuration.

For instance, you could go with [AIMP](https://www.aimp.ru/).

- play/pause is by default bound to <kbd>Space</kbd> key
- autoplay can be quickly disabled by clicking AIMP logo in top left -> `Preferences` -> `Player` -> `Automatic` -> tick `and suspend the playback`

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be the space bar, or may it also be the ENTER key? I have created [Replayer](https://replayer.app/), a tool mainly aimed at rehearsals, which quite perfectly suits your needs.

[image: Replayer usage]

- First, create a compilation of music files (mp3, wav, ...)
- In the session, using Replayer on your portable device, play any part of your set with the click of a button. By default it stops at each track's end.
  You can then click on the next song.
- Additionally, you can use a (bluetooth) numeric keypad, as a remote control